# data in alert box through linq

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq

i try to show result in alert box

i try this

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string Jqufunc(int yearP)
    {
        string res = "[";
        ProjectdbEntities a = new ProjectdbEntities();
        var b = a.Catg_type;
        foreach (var c in b)
        {

            res += "'" + c.Catg_type1 + "',";
        }
        res = res.Substring(0, res.Length - 1);
        res += "]";

        var allprogs = a.Program_type;
        string res2 = "[";
        foreach (var pr in allprogs)
        {
            res2 += "{name: '" + pr.Prog_name + "',";

            //var y = a.Year_info;



            var allcats = a.Catg_type;
            res2 += "data:[";


            var query = (a.Std_info.Join(a.Catg_type, stdtable => stdtable.Catg_id,
                catg => catg.Catg_id, (stdtable, catg) => new {stdtable, catg})
                .Join(a.Program_type, t => t.stdtable.Prog_id, prog => prog.Prog_id, (t, prog) => new {t, prog})
                .Join(a.Year_info, t => t.t.stdtable.year_id, yea => yea.year_id, (t, yea) => new {t, yea})
                .Where(t=>t.t.t.stdtable.year_id==yearP)
                .GroupBy(
                    t =>
                   new { t.t.t.catg.Catg_type1, t.t.prog.Prog_name, t.yea.year, t.t.t.stdtable.Catg_id },
                    t => t.t.t.stdtable)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    g.Key.Catg_type1,
                    g.Key.Prog_name,
                    g.Key.year,
                    g.Key.Catg_id,
                    total_students = g.Select(p=>p.Catg_id).Distinct().Count()
                })).ToList();


            res2 = res2.Substring(0, res2.Length - 1);



        }
            res2 += "]";
            res2 += "},";
            return res + "*" + res2;

    }
```

i try to show in alert box 
var webmethod = 'WebForm1.aspx/Jqufunc';

```
        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: webmethod,
            data: JSON.stringify({ yearP: $('#DropDownList1').val() }),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response.d));;
```

i have a dropdown in page  i filled this dropdown from db
when i select year suppose i select 2014 year from drop down then according to the year 2014 following data is save in db

```
Catg_type       Prog_name   year    total_students
ComputerScience Bachelors   2014    1
Management      Bachelors   2014    1
Finance         Masters      2014   3
Management       Masters     2014   2
```

now i want this in alert box

**['Management','ComputerScience','Finance']
[{name:'Bachelors','2014',data:1,1,0**

name :'Masters,'2014, data:2,0,3}]

but currently data is displayed in alert box like this 
**['Management','ComputerScience','Finance']
[{name:Bachelors,data:}{name:Masters,data:}]**

Comment: Would you be more specific with what is shown in alert and what you actually need ...

Comment: i already mention that

Comment: jsfiddle please...

Comment: do not construct json on your own.. You can simply create a class and fill the values in it, then use libraries like `JsonConverter` or `NewtonSoft` to create a json out of your class.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert("Name: " + response.d.Prog_name + ", Type: "+ response.d.Catg_type);
```